# Copying blob to another storage account using REST API gives 404 error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In the Logic App I'm using [Blob Service Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob) to copy blob between different accounts.

I have SAS signatures on both source and destination URLs. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

**Update**

The destination URL (with SAS) is obtained from Dynamics 365 endpoint. It comes back with `sv` value of 2014-02-14. Could this be the problem (the `sv` is too old as suggested in the comments)?

I managed to copy the blob in a different way, by reading the contents of the source blob and creating the blob at the destination URL with that content ([Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob)).

[image]

Comment: May be the `sv` is old? In the doc, `Beginning with version 2015-04-05, you may also specify a shared access signature for the destination blob if it is in a different storage account.`

Comment: The Service Version is generated with that value. The SAS itself seems to be fresh. I can access the blob directly in browser with that SAS (it's in a private container by default).

Comment: I think you could try to regenerate the SAS, on my side, the `sv` always be `2017-11-09`.

Comment: @JoyWang, sv is not a problem here, 2017-04-17 is fresh enough, since it depends on the version of storage client library, not the date when the SAS was generated.

Comment: @erdinger Have you included all the required headers mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob?

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft I only included `x-ms-copy-source`, it seems that it should be enough based on Joy Wang's answer.

Comment: The destination URI (with SAS) is obtained from Dynamics 365 endpoint and it comes back with `sv` value of 2014-02-14. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @JoyWang Like you mentioned, maybe the `sv` is too old?

Comment: I think this is obviously the problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gZPn.png

Comment: @JoyWang Feel free to post it as the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer, may be you could mark it for others to refer.

Answer (score 2):

Some information for you to refer.

I generate the SAS token in the portal, and copy the blob in storage account A to B, I test it in the logicapp, it works fine.

**Generate SAS:**

[image]

**Request URL:**

```
Put https://storageB.blob.core.windows.net/containername/testcopy1?sv=2017-11-09&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2018-08-27T10:43:40Z&st=2018-08-27T02:43:40Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxx
```

**Request Headers:**

```
x-ms-copy-source:https://storageA.blob.core.windows.net/containername/2.5.txt?sv=2017-11-09&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2018-08-27T10:59:19Z&st=2018-08-27T02:59:19Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxx
```

**In the LogicApp:**

[image]

**Check in the portal:**

[image]

**Update**：

I think this is obviously the problem.

Refer to: [version mentioned in the article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gZPn.png)

Comment: I tried generating the account-level SAS in the portal and that did not work for me.

Comment: Maybe that has to do with `sv` on the destination URL, as you mentioned.

Comment: @erdinger My storage account is V2 and resource manage type, how about yours? Because on my side, it always be sv=2017-11-09

Comment: I'm requesting the writable URL from Dynamics 365 (it uses its own blob storage). The environment returns sv=2014-02-14

Comment: @erdinger I think the storage library of its storage could be old, and not support the copy blob api. I recommend you to post the issue in the github or in the [azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) it may be helpful.